# To handle the click event of tag in javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am new to JavaScript. How to handle `click` event of tag `<a href="tel:+9199000000"></a>?`

For example:
web page might contain any number of tag like this: `<a href="tel:+919911111111"></a>`
Now I want to handle which tag is clicked.

So I tried following code:enter code here

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

 <a href="tel:+910000000000"><b>+(91)-0000000000</b></a>
 <a href="tel:+910000000000"><b>+(91)-0000000000</b></a>
 <a href="tel:+910000000000"><b>+(91)-0000000000</b></a>
 <a href="www.google.com"></a>
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var telLinks = document.querySelectorAll('a[href^="tel:"]');

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
"The second teltag is: " +
telLinks[1].innerHTML;

document.getElementById("demo").onclick = function() {myFunction()};

function myFunction() {

}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

So how to handle click event of clicked tag?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please extend your question with what you tried.

Comment: Just as a little note: `<a href="tel:+9199000000">` is not a _tel_  tag it is still an `a` tag having a `href` with `tel:`  as protocol.

Comment: If this is soo simple, then please provide the solution, if the question isn't clear, please ask for more info like @MartinJ. did(+1 for your comment). How the hell can you guys give a negative for someone who just entered SO. just give a detailing first like provide more code or brief your question etc...

Comment: You know how to retrieve those tags (`document.querySelectorAll('a[href^="tel:"]')`)  and you know how to add a click handler - even if it is not the best way to add one - `.onclick = function() {myFunction()};`. So where is your problem when adding the `onclick` to each element you get a s result of your `querySelectorAll`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 options.

1. With jquery

   ```
   $('a[href^="tel:"]').click(function(e){
          e.preventDefault();
          var _href = $(this).attr('href'); // link on which user clicked

   });
   ```
2. Without jquery

   a. Add a `class="tel_anchor"` to all such anchor tags which have the "tel" format.

   b. Add a click event handler to all elements of this class and handle the next step within that handler.

Comment: The OP already uses `document.querySelectorAll('a[href^="tel:"]')`  so I don't see a benefit of adding `class="tel_anchor"` except for backwards compatibility.

Comment: @web-nomad,@t.niese - still I am not able to handle event for all elements though I am using querySelectorAll